# Is this NoSql schema correct?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I start to use Firebase and NoSql, I'd like to understand best practice, so I try to create this schema with orders, order_rows and articles. The main query is to show specific order so I create this:

```
    {
    "orders": {
        "1": {
            "date": "1/1/2016",
            "row_order": {
                "1": true,
                "2": true
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "date": "1/1/2016",
            "row_order": {
                "3": true
            }
        }
    },
    "articles": {
        "1": {
            "name": "a"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "b"
        }
    },
    "row_orders": {
        "1": {
            "quantity": 7,
            "id_article": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "quantity": 2,
            "id_article": 2
        },
        "3": {
            "quantity": 4,
            "id_article": 2
        }
    }
}
```

When I must show order number 1, I can find order rows and then from row orders detect articles.

I don't use classic sql schema (row_orders with id_article and id_order) to semplify get data.

Is this correct? Or How I can do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to say of a NoSQL data structure is *correct*. If you want to learn about NoSQL, I recommend reading the [Firebase documentation on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and some of the older blog posts on the Firebase blog (such as [this one](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html)).

One immediate problem in your data structure is that you use pseudo array-indices as the keys for your data. These will lead to a hard time, since Firebase will try to interpret them as actual array indices (meaning you get back an array with an empty first element) and it doesn't scale over many users or users who may be offline. Read more about this in the [blog post on arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).